# Prove that if $\xi$ is a bounded random variable then $\xi$ is $\phi _2$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $\xi$ be a real random variable. We say that $\xi$ $\in$ $\phi _2$ when $\exists  \lambda >0$ such that $\mathbb{E}\left(exp\left(\frac{\xi^2}{\lambda^2}\right)\right) \le e$.

**My problem:** Prove that if $\xi$ is a bounded random variable then $\xi$ is $\phi _2$.

Although I tried to find a solution, it didn't work. Some hints on the internet said that we can use Hoeffding's inequality but I don't know how to do it. Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M>0$ be a real number such that $|ξ|\leq M$ (which exists, as we assume $ξ$ to be bounded) and set $λ=M$. Then
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{ξ^2}{λ^2}\right)\right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{M^2}{λ^2}\right)\right] = \mathbb{E}[e]=e.$$

Comment: Ohh, I thought it was too complicated. Thank you.